# How to overwrite my all local changes in XCode repo when I see "Rebase local changes onto upstream changes" message?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a Bitbucket repo where the most recent changes are pushed by another developer teammate. His push is more important and I want to make sure my local is same as the latest in the repo. I have not made any changes but still Xcode shows me this warning. I am fine is all my local is overwritten. How do I do it? Should I check the box when I am pulling changes in Xcode from the BitBucket repo? Or do I need to do a git pull from terminal?

Comment: Please elaborate the error and if possible then post the logs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge another branch into yours, you should always commit your changes first. When conflicts emerge, you just solve them and there you go, you are on the latest commit with your changes preserved.

If, however, you prefer rebase instead of merge - you HAVE to commit your uncommited changes first, then you can rebase on the latest commit from the other developer's branch, the nice thing about rebase is that it keeps the git history cleaner while also leading you trough the conflict solving, because it basically tries to put each commit of yours on top of the commit that you are rebasing onto, so it sort of "guides" you trough resolving conflicts as you have small chunks of code to resolve and then continue rebase.

Try to read more on this. This article summarises the difference between merge and rebase:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-git-merge-and-rebase-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them-131b863785f/